# What I should write in StackApplet settings to follow Askubuntu?

Tags: applet

I've installed StackApplet but I can't link it to my askubuntu account. I have to fill two fields, "Site name" and "User id". I think that ubuntu.stackexchange is the site name and skalka my user id, but the applet keeps hanging on "Please wait...".

Comment: What version of StackApplet are you using?

Comment: Is this really a meta question? He's asking how to use a gnome applet that's part of the ubuntu repositories. If this was an applet that checked his twitter account or his email, this question would be perfectly on-topic on the main site, no?

Comment: I use StackApplet 1.2.0, with numerical id it works. Thanks.

Comment: @sepp2k Ah you bring up a good point, I originally flagged it as meta as most discussion on tools to integrate with Ask Ubuntu have been on meta. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Site name is "askubuntu" or "ubuntu.stackexchange" without the ".com".

In the user id field, you're supposed to enter your numerical, unique id, not your name. So in your case 4180.

Comment: `ubuntu.stackexchange` won't work anymore, I'm afraid.